# Updatedb include the path pointed by symbolic link

Tags: symlink, gnu, database, locate, updatedb

I have created `mlocate` database with the contents of a particular folder. I see that the `updatebd` doesn't include the path pointed by the symbolic links in the database.

How can I include the path pointed by the symbolic links in the database?

**Surprisingly**: *mlocate* has a default option `-L` or `--follow` that follows trailing symbolic links when checking file existence (default).

> What purpose does it serves when *updatedb* doesn't include symlinks!

---

Refer:

- [updatedb(8): update database for mlocate - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb)
- [mlocate - Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Mlocate)

Comment: slightly off-topic: I prefer to not have `updatedb` installed in VMs.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sorry I don't get your point, I too don't have updatedb installed in VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this implementation](https://plocate.sesse.net/) of plocate with updatedb in it, one can build a custom version to follow symlinks. I don't know if it answers the question also for mlocate, I only use plocate.

If you are certain there will be no loop in your filesystem, you can simply replace the code

```cpp
e.is_directory = (de->d_type == DT_DIR);
```

by

```cpp
e.is_directory = (de->d_type == DT_DIR) || (de->d_type == DT_LNK); // or even just true
```

in the file `updatedb.cpp`.

If you might have loops, here is a solution (maybe not very efficient). Always in `updatedb.cpp`, declare a global variable `vector<char*> explored;` just before the function `int scan(...)`. Then, add the following code after the two first tests in that function `scan`:

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
realpath(path.c_str(),buf);
for (auto &e : explored)
  if (strcmp(e,buf) == 0)
    return 0;
explored.push_back(buf);
```

And just before each `return` of that function, add an `explored.pop_back();`.

With similar modifications of the code, one can follow symlinks only when inside certain directories, and/or completely exclude some directories of the database, depending on one's need. It is also quite useful to make the results [clickable](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda).